# Find a single doc using the doc._id and a another parameter

Tags: node.js, express, couchdb

I have failed to find an answer for this so I'm giving asking a shot:

I have a DB that has documents stored that have various properties including a `uuid` that represents the user who is currently using the app. I need to fetch a single document by its `_id` field but I only want it returned if the `uuid` field matches the current user. I only know the current user's `uuid` at runtime so the request needs to be dynamic.

I have attempted to solve this with several different types of views and queries. The latest attempt is below.

View inside of the design document:

```
    "current_user_passed_id": {
        "map": "function(doc){ if(doc.type && doc.type == 'my_doc' && doc._id && doc.uuid) emit([doc._id, doc.uuid], doc)}"
    }
```

Query:

```
/db/design/_design_name/_view/current_user_passed_id?key=["6e08fe0e990f73593300df411f023ec4", "9698fde5-99b9-4693-8f78-b2ae8a7f03e0"]
```

In the above query, `6e08fe0e990f73593300df411f023ec4` is the `doc._id` and `9698fde5-99b9-4693-8f78-b2ae8a7f03e0` is the `doc.uuid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couch DB map functions always have the `_id` property so that check was not needed in the conditional of the function. I also needed to use the `startkey` and `endkey` query params in my query instead of the `key` param. The `startkey` and the `endkey` both take the same array, since I'm only after a single document.

Below is my revised and working code:

View inside of the design document:

```
    "current_user_passed_id": {
        "map": "function(doc){ if(doc.type && doc.type == 'key_doc' && doc.uuid) emit([doc._id, doc.uuid], doc)}"
    }
```

Query:

```
/db/_design/keys/_view/current_user_passed_id?startkey=["6e08fe0e990f73593300df411f023ec4", "9698fde5-99b9-4693-8f78-b2ae8a7f03e0"]&endkey=["6e08fe0e990f73593300df411f023ec4", "9698fde5-99b9-4693-8f78-b2ae8a7f03e0"]
```